# Send child element to front

Tags: css

Is there a way to have a child element of div1 be in front of the div2, without the other elements of div 1 being in front of div2?

By that I mean given this:

[image]

Can I get this?

[image]

Or this:

[image]

Or if not, is there someway to recreate that? Would I need to use a 2x2 grid and separate the pointer/triangle from the speech bubble?

Comment: Have you tried z-index on the child element?

Comment: you will need to add `position:relative; z-index: 10` to the child element. You can use z-index:1 as well. 10 is just an example

Comment: you will need to add `position:relative; z-index: 10` to the child element. You can use z-index:1 as well. 10 is just an example

Comment: you will need to add `position:relative; z-index: 10` to the child element. You can use z-index:1 as well. 10 is just an example

Comment: Thanks, I did use z-index but I tried sending elements to the back unsuccessfully, didn't realize I should have been sending the one I wanted to the front.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) on your child element, make sure to give it `position` also.

Comment: this should be in the comments! :)

Answer (score 0):

While the obvious solution would seem to be z-index be aware of this (from MDN)

> The z-index CSS property sets the z-order of a **positioned** element and its descendants

Here's a simple example which produces this:

[image]

```css
.div1 {
  width: 30vmin;
  height: 30vmin;
  background: magenta;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: lime;
  width: 20vmin;
  height: 40vmin;
}

.div2 {
  background: cyan;
  width: 30vmin;
  height: 30vmin;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="child">CHILD</div>
</div>
<div class="div2">
</div>
```

Depending on the complexity of your HTML structure you may also need to look more closely at the order in which stacking contexts are interpreted/created see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Answer (score 0):

you can use `z-index:val>0` or `overflow:hidden` in the **child** css.

for exemple :

```
.child {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

or

```
.child {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```